# web based workflow solution

Tags: workflow, business-process-management, diagrams

The main task is to work on documents which go through some specific workflow which is represented by a lucid graph (diagram). We need document versioning, different roles & permissions and most importantly we need to let the users create the workflow graphs (with all those guard conditions for transitions, mail notifications, calendar events and stuff).

I've seen some solutions none of which fulfill the last requirement. Any web-based open source solution is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As above, BEA Aqualogic Studio is really great, but it is rather expensive.
Take a look at Intalio BPM, It's open source and it is BPMN 2.0 compliant.

JBoss has some products similar to those offered by BEA, and they're free.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into BEA Weblogic?